# Agregar un Xml a un nodo pero en una etiqueta CDATA

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2015

Trabajo con Visual Studio 2015, Windows Forms
Necesito crear un xml con el siguiente formato.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

```
<estado>AUTORIZADO</estado>

<numeroAutorizacion>2607201701099034023400120120010085477160854771613</numeroAutorizacion>

<fechaAutorizacion>2017-07-26T02:25:27-05:00</fechaAutorizacion>

<ambiente>PRODUCCIÓN</ambiente>

<comprobante>

    <![CDATA[


            ]]>

</comprobante>

<mensajes/>
```

Si puedo crear el xml pero **¿no se como agregar el CDATA al nodo ?**

He intentado con este código

```
private void CrearXml(string destinoRutaArchivo, string estado, string numeroAutorizacion,
        string fechaAutorizacion, string ambiente, string comprobante, string path)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(destinoRutaArchivo)) { Directory.CreateDirectory(destinoRutaArchivo); }
        foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(destinoRutaArchivo, "*.*"))
        {
            File.SetAttributes(item, FileAttributes.Normal);
            File.Delete(item);
        }

        XDocument configuracionXml = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
            new XElement("autorizacion",
                new XElement("estado", estado),
                new XElement("numeroAutorizacion", numeroAutorizacion),
                new XElement("fechaAutorizacion", fechaAutorizacion),
                new XElement("ambiente", ambiente),
                new XElement("comprobante", comprobante))
            );

        configuracionXml.Element("comprobante").Add(
            new XElement("CDataElement", new XCData(comprobante)));

        configuracionXml.Save(path);
    }
```

Nota en el nodo comprobante le agrego una variable de tipo string en el cual me trae un xml aprobado de un Web Service.

Me da error de referencia no estableciada como referencia del objeto en la linea donde pongo el Add.
Saludos!

Comment: Igual el error que te da, no tiene nada que ver con agregar el CData.. el error te lo da porque no encuentra el elemento comprobante.. porque no esta en el raiz, si no uno para adentro.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el contenido del campo comprobante?
¿Lleva llaves o &lt; &gt;?

Comment: @JLPrieto es una variable estring en la cual me trae un xml lleva <![CDATA[


            ]]>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que el tag `comprobante` es el `CDate` no tienes que agregar otor tag asicional

```
 XDocument configuracionXml = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
            new XElement("autorizacion",
                new XElement("estado", estado),
                new XElement("numeroAutorizacion", numeroAutorizacion),
                new XElement("fechaAutorizacion", fechaAutorizacion),
                new XElement("ambiente", ambiente),
                new XElement("comprobante",  new XCData(comprobante))
            );
```

La parte donde agregar el `CDataElement` deberias quitarlo porque ese es un nuevo tag dentro del `comprobante`